# Deducing a supremum from a given property

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $$ S = \bigg\{ { \frac{x^2}{1+2x^2} } :x\in\mathbb{R}\bigg\}$$ 
we may guess that $\sup A=\frac{1}{2}$

But how does one prove this without taking limits?

Answer (score 0):

If $x = 0$ then the fraction is $0$. If $x \neq 0$, then
$$
\frac{x^{2}}{1 + 2x^{2}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{2}} + 2} \leq \frac{1}{2}.
$$
There is no $r > 2$ such that $1/r$ is instead the supremum of the set; for every $r > 2$ there is some real $x$ such that 
$$
\frac{x^{2}}{1+2x^{2}} > \frac{1}{r},
$$
say $x := 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{r-2}}$.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the result that I have proved?

Comment: Oh they are equivalent. So taking a more convenient way suffices :). I only broke it into two stages. First to show that $1/2$ is an upper bound, second that $1/2$ is least (no smaller one would be possible).

Comment: How are they equivalent?

Comment: No they are not. I misread what you wrote. I cannot see how the result can be useful here. You want to use the pertinent results.

Comment: Can I say " Let $1/2 - \epsilon = 1/r$ for some $r>2$ " and conclude that there will be no lower upper bound than $1/2$ ?

Comment: You may. But one of $\varepsilon, r$ is redundant. Using the form $1/2 - \varepsilon$ would be more cumbersome to give an example of $x$. The numbers of the form $1/r$ where $r > 2$ are the numbers $1/2 - \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Alright, I will use a more standard technique - thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome. And, you know, actually it ain't about being standard! It is about which one is more convenient for a given situation. Hope you can see this.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound for $S$. In fact

$$\frac{x^2}{1+2x^2} =\frac{1}{2} \frac{2x^2}{1+2x^2}\le\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+2x^2}{1+2x^2}= \frac{1}{2} $$

for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Moreover,

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+2x^2} =\frac{1}{2} $$

and so for any $\varepsilon >0$

$$\left|\frac{x^2}{1+2x^2}-\frac{1}{2} \right|<\varepsilon $$

for $x$ large enough. In particular, for $x$ large enough, we have

$$\frac{x^2}{1+2x^2} > \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon, $$

so the desired supremu is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you show that

$$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$

and also

$$f(x)<\frac{1}{2} \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x$$

you are done.

The second condition can be shown by showing that the function is monotonically increasing on $[0,\infty]$ and monotonically decreasing on $[-\infty,0)$

Comment: This is a more calculus based approach, I want a more analytical proof that doesn't use calculus.

Comment: @AnInvisibleCarrot, OK, you might wanna ignore my solution and have a look at the other answers. Hope you find what you need.

Comment: Your solution is fine if we are allowed to take limits :)